# Why userA$ sudo su userB -c 'printenv' isn't printing environment details of userB

Tags: linux, shell, unix, environment-variables

I have two users userA and userB.

I want to print the env details of userB. I am running the below command from userA.

```
userA$ sudo su userB -c 'printenv'
```

But it prints the environment details of userA. How to solve that ?

If i switch to userB and do `printenv` then it prints the environment details of userB as expected. Samething is happening with `PYTHONPATH` and other variables also.

Note I need to run the command like that in a single command. I can't first switch to userB then run `printenv`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you need to type `su - userB` instead of `su userB`.

Comment: this belongs on [su]

Comment: @DanielA.White: Or [UNIX.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use this:

```
userA$ sudo su - userB -c 'printenv'
```

**su** with hyphen (**-**) changes the environmental variables to those of the new user as dictated by their ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 1):

From the su manpage from July 2014:

> It is recommended to always use the `--login` option (instead
>   of its shortcut `-`)  to  avoid side effects caused by mixing
>   environments.

and

> #### `-`, `-l`, `--login`
>
> Start the shell as a login shell with an environment similar to a real login:
>
> - clears all the environment variables except `TERM`
> - initializes the environment variables `HOME`, `SHELL`, `USER`, `LOGNAME`, and `PATH`
> - changes to the target user's home directory
> - sets `argv[0]` of the shell to '`-`' in order to make the shell a login shell

When the shell is a login shell, its startup process is different from when it is a interactive shell. The bash manpage gives further information about this.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing your concepts.  Environment variables belong to a *process*, not to a *user*.  As a user, I have many processes with differing environments.

It seems that you are interested in finding the environment thu user's *login shell* would have.  For that you can give `su` any of `-`, `-l`, `--login` command option:

> #### `-`, `-l`, `--login`
>
> Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.
>
> When `-` is used, it must be specified before any username. For portability it is recommended to use it as last option, before any
>   username. The other forms (`-l` and `--login`) do not have this
>   restriction.

Do be aware that the user's init files may not generate exactly the same environment as you get - for example, if any of the initialization is dependent on the terminal type, on whether `$DISPLAY` is set, or on the phase of the moon.

You should also consider `sudo -i` which may give a simpler command compared to `sudo su -`, to much the same effect.